# css3 last-child syntax not working

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am unable to make the last-child pseudo class affect the last list item. What is the mistake in my css syntax? The URL = http://chesstao.com

I am unable to make the last-child pseudo element affect the last list item. What is the mistake in my css syntax?

```
 HTML:
 <section class="top-bar-section">

 <ul class="right"> 

 <li class="has-dropdown">
 <a href="#">instruction</a>
 <ul class="dropdown">
 <li><a class="plain" href="#">Students</a></li>

 <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">my rates</a></li>

 </ul>
 </li>

 </ul>

 CSS3:

 .top-bar-section ul li.has-dropdown ul.dropdown:last-child {background:red !important;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you are missing a `</li>` closing tag

```
<li>
    <a class="plain has-dropdown" href="products.php" >Products</a>
</li>
```

and it is

```
ul.dropdown li:last-child {background:red;}
```

and you dont need  `!important`

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/fsFLy/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
.top-bar-section ul li.has-dropdown ul.dropdown li:last-child {background:red !important;}
```

So, you have to specify element tag (li) in this case, which is last child of parent ul...